# Enable 'Send Do Not Track requests' in Microsoft Edge - Command

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-edge

In Windows 10, how do I turn on 'Send Do Not Track requests' for the Microsoft Edge browser? -- Through the command prompt/batch script.

Comment: I moved it over to Super User. Sorry for posting it on the wrong site.
Is there a way to delete this or does a mod have to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\Main" /v DoNotTrack /t REG_DWORD /d 0x00000001 /f >nul 2>&1
```